# Is Locking this instance method required

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

For the question that I have probably I need more convincing answer to implement in my solution. I am not sure whether my understanding is correct. Following are the implementation details:

In a class, in the main method, where the class object C is created to call an instance method that takes integer as a parameter:

```
public <AnyClass> MyMethod(int classVar)
{
    return new <AnyClass>(classVar);
    // Can have more implementation, using the parameter passed
}
```

In the main, I want this method to be called on the multiple threads, using the same class object, the parameter would be the value supplied by for loop that starts the threads to execute. Now in memory we are executing same method, does this needs any kind of locking. In my view No, I have tested, but I am not sure in theory why, wouldn't different threads mess up with each other's parameter value, in my implementation it doesn't seems the case.

Only thing I cannot guarantee, is which thread access and returns first as that would not be in the order, but if I do not care about it, is this implementation correct.

Please note, this is an attempt to describe the issue in a stand alone manner, I have similar implementation as part of a complex project.

Any suggestions / pointers would be great. Please let me know if you need a clarification.

Comment: If `return new AnyClass(classVar);` is all it does then no. If there's other stuff happening then it all depends on whether it's modifying shared resources.

Comment: Local variables and function parameters passed by value don't need to be synchronized, they are unique in every thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are absolutely correct!

no sort of locking is required. locking is required when the code within the method accesses something other than what came through the parameters. if your code accesses instance variables or singleton objects then you *might* need locking. i say *might* because if your code accesses these external data in read-only manner then you wont need locking.

fundamentally, you need locking if and only if two parallel threads access and mutate (change) any data shared between them.

as for the method-arguments, they are personal to each thread. two threads can invoke same method, at the same time with different arguments. both threads will work fine. as long as the code is confined to working with only the data it got in the arguments.

in the sample code, you did not access any *shared-data*, hence locking is not required. hope you are convinced enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to lock anything here:

- Code is read-only, so two threads executing the same code have no problem.
- Each thread has its own stack, so threads can't mess up each other's stack-based variables.

However, when two threads may see the same object, and at least one modifies it, you may need to lock that object.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response, it is on the line of my understanding, I know modification of a shared resource cannot be done without Locking, here on return I just add the value to List type for usage down the line, so seems like no issue with the MT implementation

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing any shared resources in your method as it is written (assuming the constructor to AnyClass also doesn't)

In addition, the parameter (int) that you are passing in, is passed by value, so even if your method did change it, it would only change a local copy of it on the stack of the method being called.

So from what you've shown, there is no need to do any locking.  The sort of thing where you would need to lock might be if you were passing in the same instance of an object into your method and then doing something to change the state of that object, in which case you would need to synchronize access to the state of the object.